# Difference between the volume/covolume of a lattice

Tags: measure-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices, lattices-in-lie-groups

I am trying to learn some basic knowledge on lattices for studying Minkowski's theorems and Dirichlet's unit theorem. My problem is, I could not build the basics of  lattice theory and there are some blurred parts. I will give some definitons and then ask my *questions*.

Let $L \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a lattice. It is a set $\{ \sum \alpha_i x_i | \alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ where $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So we can either say that $L$ is the set above or we can define a matrix $$B=[ (x_1)_{n\times 1}   \dots (x_n)_{n \times 1}]_{n \times n}$$- generator matrix of $L$- 
and say $L = \{Bv : v \in \mathbb{Z}^{n \times 1} \}$.

I saw that $vol(L)$ is defined as Lebesgue measure $\mu(P)$ where $P=\{ \sum a_i x_i | 0\le a_i <1 \}$, the parallelpipped of $L$ with respect to base $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.
Now,

i)Is $vol(L) = \det(B)$, or, $\det(B)=vol(\mathbb{R}^n / L)$?  If the latter is correct, what is $\mathbb{R}^n / L$, exactly?

ii)What is the difference between covolume$(L)$ and volume$(L)$?

Comment: Could you please say what $\Lambda$ is or explain how $\Lambda$ is related to $L$?

Comment: My bad, it must be $L$. I have edited the question.

Comment: In algebraic number theory you need to show any integer matrix is $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$-similar to a matrix in *Hermite normal form*, whose effect on lattices, determinant and volume/covolume is obvious.  And $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is by definition the group sending $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to itself.

Comment: $L$ is a discrete set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, as well as a group of translations. It is uniquely determined by the HNF of $B$.  And formally $\mathbb{R}^n / L = \{ x+L, x \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ is the quotient of the space by a (discrete) group of translations, that you can think as the parallepiped $P$ with a special topology on the boundary making it a torus $\mathbf{T}^n$ (but you can replace $P$ by any fundamental domain it works too and doesn't change its volume).

Answer (score 2):

Let's think of $\mathbb R^n$ as an abelian topological group, and a lattice $L$ as a discrete subgroup. Then (maybe A. Weil proved such a thing in his book on topological groups; in any case, it is standard) the topological group *quotient* $\mathbb R^n/L$ has a unique (positive, regular, Borel) measure $d\dot{x}$ such that for every $f\in C^o_c(\mathbb R^n/L)$
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)\;dx \;=\; \int_{\mathbb R^n/L} \sum_{\lambda\in L} f(\dot{x}+\lambda)\;d\dot{x}
$$
In the tangible case at hand, for your choice of $\mathbb Z$-basis for $L$, the characteristic function of a "fundamental period parallelogram" for $L$ maps to the identically-$1$ function on the quotient, whose integral on the quotient is the natural volume of it.

(It's not quite the determinant, but, rather, the absolute value thereof...)

EDIT: in response to a comment... one way to see the relationship between (absolute values of) the determinant (of a matrix whose columns (or rows) are a chosen $\mathbb Z$-basis for the given lattice), is to invoke the volume-preserving feature of "shear" matrices, e.g, upper-triangular with $1$'a on the diagonal. One can give a physical plausibility argument that "volume" (perhaps ambiguously defined) is preserved by these. Also, for example, by orthogonal matrices (since they preserve the metric). Every linear transformation is expressible (Iwasawa decomposition...) as $g=nak$, where $n$ is a "shear" map, $k$ is orthogonal, and $a$ is *diagonal*. The effect of diagonal matrices on "volume" is obviously the absolute value of the product of the diagonal entries. :)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Unfortunately, the determiant related arguments are still not clear for me. Can you please enlighten me in "the language of determinants" ?