# show that $f(x)=a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$ is smooth on $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, integer-lattices

The space of lattices in the Euclidean plane $X=\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ can it have smooth functions? I'm trying to find examples of $C^\infty$ functions.  Consider equivalence classes of matrices (lattices)
$$ f: \left\{ x=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\ c & d \end{array}
 \right)  : ad-bc=1\right\} \mapsto a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2\in \mathbb{R}$$
Can we show this function is smooth? $f(x)\in C^\infty(X)$

Comment: With $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ inheriting of the $\mathbb{R}^4$ topology then $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is discrete so there is an open set such that $D \cap \gamma D = \emptyset$ for all $\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and for any $f \in C^\infty_c(D)$ then $F(x)=\sum_{\gamma \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})} f(\gamma x)$ is $C^\infty(SL_2(\mathbb{R}))$ and left $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ invariant. If you meant analytic instead of smooth then it is another story but $F(x)=\sum_{\gamma\in\mathbb{Z}^4,ad-bc=1}\exp(-a_{\gamma x}^2-b_{ \gamma x}^2-c_{ \gamma x}^2-d_{ \gamma x}^2)$ is analytic and left $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ invariant.

Comment: @reuns That's an interesting thought. Given a function $f(x)$ on $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ we can take the average over the  $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ images $f(\gamma x)$. What about the co-area or the [co-volume](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360002/difference-between-the-volume-covolume-of-a-lattice) of the lattice, is that smooth? What about $f(x)= (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 )^{-k}$ what power of $k$ leads to convergent sum? I think that is called Eisenstein series.

Comment: If $\sum_{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{Z}^4}' (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^k$ converges then so does $\sum_{\gamma\in\mathbb{Z}^4,ad-bc=1}(a_{\gamma x}^2+b_{ \gamma x}^2+c_{ \gamma x}^2+d_{ \gamma x}^2)^k$ which is then holomorphic thus analytic in each entry of $x \in SL_2$. I don't see what you mean with you other claims.